# How do i connect to database after i installed SSIS 2012?

Tags: ssis-2012

I am trying to connect to database from Integration Service project from Microsoft visual studio. How do I create a database from SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: did you try Google before posting a question here ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) will allow you to create a database and tables through its graphical user interface.  However, I'm guessing what you're looking for is actually an SSIS Connection Manager to an existing database.  Look at the connection managers in SSIS, create a new one, and fill in the boxes.  What you're doing is building a database connection string.  You will need credentials (username and password, or a Windows authenticated user) to connect to the database.  Also, you may need to spend some time reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks..finally I connected to database in SSIS